# Discord Bot Development: How do I stop this infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This calls and retrieves a dog url from random.dog, when posting the link to log it stops at one, however when using message.channel.send below it runs an infinite loop of the call, what would be the best way to prevent this and to only send one link then stop till it is called again?

```
const animals = require('relevant-animals')

client.on("message", (message) => {                   
if(message.content.includes("dog")){ 
animals.dog().then(s => message.channel.send(s)) ; 
animals.dog().then(s => console.log(s)) ;
};
```

Below is console log after one request it sends one link
[image: This is console log after one request it sends one link]

Below is after it is sent to the channel, it just posts links non stop rather than just the one as shown in the console

[image: This is after send to channel]

Comment: What do you mean by infinite loop? Could you post some output for reference?

Comment: added some images, it posts links non stop rather than just one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your bot is responding to itself. You can exclude it for replying to itself by using `message.author.bot`.

```
if(!message.author.bot) {
   // Do something if message doesn't come from a bot.
}
```

I hope this code will help you getting on the right path, good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it!

Comment: Good thinking. I usually just use ```if(message.author.bot) { return; }``` but this is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this:

```
if(message.author.bot) return;
```

This wouldn't only stop bot from executing commands etc. on itself, it would prevent any bot from using your bot.

Since it checks for author of message if bot property returns true it would `return;`.

And if bot property returns false it would work as normally - only for users like you and me, and many others!

You can try this by doing the following code:

```
console.log(message.author.bot);
```

It will log the boolean value of bot property of the messages author.
[You can read more about booleans **(true/false)** here.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp)